# How to set content of ReactQuill programatically

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use [ReactQuill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) and set the content of the editor from data coming from an API. This is what I have so far, but it is not working:

```
  const editor_ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setValue( value );
  };

  const getData = () => {
    getDataFromAPI.then((data) => {
      if (data && data.data) {
        setValue(data.data );
        editor_ref.current.getEditor().setContents(data.data);
      }
    });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []); 

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px", maxWidth: "520px", margin: "auto" }}>

    <div className="text-editor">
          <ReactQuill
            theme="snow"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder={"Write something awesome..."}
            ref={editor_ref}
          />
    </div>

  );
```

Anyone has used this library can say what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging and check Quill source code, I found out that a JSON parse was needed on the setContent method:

```
editor_ref.current.getEditor().setContents(JSON.parse(res.data.data));
```

I hope it helps anyone in the future.